# htaccess rewrite query string nothing works

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

**THE PROBLEM**

After looking at 50+ StackOverflow posts and trying many permutations of my htaccess file, it does nothing still.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

Using this website to generate my htaccess file: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Setting AllowOverride All in my httpd.conf file and restarting Apache.

**MY CURRENT HTACCESS FILE**

Lives in the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^find-a-local-doctor/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /find-a-local-doctor/?state=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

**WHAT I WANT TO ACCOMPLISH**

Change this URL:
http://www.md1network.com/find-a-local-doctor/?state=FL&city=Tampa

To this:
http://www.md1network.com/find-a-local-doctor/FL/Tampa

**ADDITIONALLY**

Since the actual file doing the work is: http://www.md1network.com/find-a-local-doctor/index.php, I need to be able to parse the query string with PHP.  Hopefully, I will still be able to do this to get the state and city.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine, what exactly is problem you're facing now. Please state clearly.

Comment: When I go to http://www.md1network.com/find-a-local-doctor/?state=FL&city=Tampa the url does not get rewritten the way I want it.  It does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing rule looks alright but you will need an additional external redirection rule for reverse. Put this rule before your existing rule (just below `RewriteBase /`).

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(find-a-local-doctor)/(?:index\.php)?\?state=([^&]+)&city=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Tried adding this to my original rule and it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Oh I had `/` missing after `find-a-local-doctor` in my rule above. Code edited , try it now.

Comment: Ok that worked, but now my page throws a 404 error instead of passing the query string arguments to the index.php page.

Comment: Also, I would like it to work for http://www.md1network.com/find-a-local-doctor/index.php?state=FL&city=Tampa

Comment: Made another edit that will take care of rewrite of `http://www.md1network.com/find-a-local-doctor/index.php?state=FL&city=Tampa`

Comment: As sorry typo. Check again I missed `:` in `?:`

Comment: That edit fixed the error, but now I would still like to putt the query string arguments are parse them with index.php in that folder.  Additionally, there will be a dynamic third argument that will eventually be a hyphenated name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37964/discussion-between-rick-s-and-anubhava)